# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Exception with MonoTouch

Tags: exception, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, ios5

I've upgraded to iOS 5 with MonoTouch 2.8 and other related updates.  I've got a UIViewController that has a UITabBarController in it with two different XIBs configured for the view.  Also have an outlet on the UITabBarController.  What I was doing in the ViewDidLoad is

```
this.View = this.TabBar.View;
```

Now with the upgrade to iOS 5 I'm getting a UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency exception with the views in the tab bar.  I can do

```
this.View.AddSubview(this.TabBar.View);
```

or

```
this.View.Add(this.TabBar.View);
```

and the exception stops happening.  The trouble though is that my tab bar becomes positioned at the bottom of the screen where only part of the image is visible and you cannot see the associated text.  In the searching I did I found a few Objective-C examples, which all look like they are using the subview route, which doesn't help.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The supported pattern in iOS4 was a bad idea: you connected view controllers by grabbing an internal (the view controller's View property) and added it to another view controller's view hierarchy.    This was not only ugly, but raised all kinds of questions about the view hierarchy.

Although Apple still supports the basic pattern, any advanced users are no longer supported, and you need to use the new viewcontroller containment setup.   These invalid uses are now raised as exceptions.

In the WWDC 2011 presentation, look for Session 102 - "Implementing UIViewController Containment."

The major changes are, for your main view controller, the one that will occupy the whole screen, you change the old:

```
window.AddSubview (myViewController.View);
```

To:

```
window.RootViewController = myViewController
```

For others, you use the new API:

```
currentContainer.AddChildViewController (myOtherViewController);
```

In your case, you are adding a new ViewController to your tab, so you would do something like this for adding your view controller to the first tab:

```
myTabBar.ViewControllers [1].AddChildViewController (myFancyController)
```

Comment: I think part of my issue may be that I'm trying to use a UITabBarController outside of the main window, which I do not think is supported.  I want to have an interior page in the application that has tabs while the main pages themselves do not.  That is the reason I was setting this.View = this.TabBar.View so that I could get the tab bar on the interior page.  Some recent reading has me thinking the tab bar is not allowed to be used like I'm trying to do.  Any idea if that is right?  Thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Right, you might need to use a PresentModalViewController instead of just assigning it to a window.

Comment: I ended taking out the internal UITabBarController since it seems to be against the intended use.  I used the toolbar on the navigation controller to present the options and allow switching.

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza - when you say the supported pattern in iOS 4, is it documented by apple kind of supported, or do you mean it's a hack that seems to work for the most part?